# Error 405 Method Not allowed when sending AJAX Post request using axios.post

Tags: html, ajax, axios, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send a post request to getData.php file to retrieve the data after user has selected an option for limit and also the option. It is supposed to display a table after the user has done selecting. However, my console display isAxiosError.js:12  POST http://127.0.0.1:5501/wk6/res/ex2/getData.php 405 (Method Not Allowed) I am not sure why it is appearing as my logic seems to be correct and I have run it using MAMP too. Thanks so much if you could explain to me...

my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link
         href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
         rel="stylesheet"
         integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx"
         crossorigin="anonymous"
      />

      <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
               <h2>Choose an option:</h2>
               <label for="limit">Limit:</label>
               <input id="limit" type="number" min="1" max="5" value="1" />
               <select onchange="getData()" id="select">
                  <option value="customers">Customers</option>
                  <option value="products">Products</option>
                  <option value="suppliers">Suppliers</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
               <div id="result"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

      <script>
         // HINT: explore https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp for creating a table

       
         function getData() {
            var type = event.target.value;
            var limit = document.getElementById("limit").value;

         
            var url = "getData.php";

            axios.post(url, {
                  type: type,
                  limit: limit,
               })
               .then(response => {
                  console.log(response.data);
                  generateTable(response.data, type);
               })
               .catch(error => {
                  console.log(error.message);
               });
         }

         function generateTable(dataObj, type) {
            var output = "<h2 class='pl-2'>" + type + ":</h2>";
            output += "<table class='mx-2 table table-dark'><tr>";

            let item = dataObj.records[0];
            for (let prop in item) {
               output += "<th>" + prop + "</th>";
            }
            output += "</tr>";
            for (let item of dataObj.records) {
               output += "<tr>";
               for (let prop in item) {
                  output += "<td>" + item[prop] + "</td>";
               }
               output += "</tr>";
            }
            output += "</table>";
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
         }
      </script>

      <script
         src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
         integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
         crossorigin="anonymous"
      ></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

getData.php file:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    // data arrays
    $customers = [ 
            ["name" => "Jack", "age" => 30, "city" => "London"],
            ["name" => "Mary", "age" => 24, "city" => "Paris"],
            ["name" => "Dan", "age" => 18, "city" => "Prague"],
            ["name" => "Olav", "age" => 32, "city" => "Moscow"],
            ["name" => "Billie", "age" => 43, "city" => "Barcelona"]
    ];

    $products = [ 
            ["name" => "iPhone", "price" => 2049],
            ["name" => "Samsung", "price" => 1699],
            ["name" => "Huawei", "price" => 1499],
            ["name" => "Oppo", "price" => 1199],
            ["name" => "LG", "price" => 1299]
    ];

    $suppliers =  [ 
            ["name" => "Bane", "age" => 35, "city" => "Tokyo"],
            ["name" => "Joker", "age" => 44, "city" => "Seoul"],
            ["name" => "Penguin", "age" => 28, "city" => "KL"],
            ["name" => "Dent", "age" => 38, "city" => "Singapore"],
            ["name" => "Fish", "age" => 40, "city" => "Jakarta"]
    ];

    $data = array();
    // default
    $limit = 1; 
    $type = "customers"; 
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $data = json_decode($json);
        $type = $data->type;
        if (isset($data->limit)) {
            $limit = $data->limit;
        }
    } else {
        $type = $_GET['type'];
        if (isset($_GET['limit'])) {
            $limit = $_GET['limit'];
        }
    }

    if($type == "customers") {
        $data = array_slice($customers, 0, $limit);
    } else if($type == "products") {
        $data = array_slice($products, 0, $limit);
    } else if($type == "suppliers") {
        $data = array_slice($suppliers, 0, $limit);
    }

    $processed_data = [ "type" => $type, "records" => $data];

    $jsonObj = json_encode($processed_data);
    
    echo $jsonObj;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding allow-methods in your CORS headers...

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *

Comment: you mean adding it on top of the getData.php file as i have added it in my getData.php

Comment: Yes you are right.